# Bootstrap three columns order

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap row of 3 columns stacked above each other on `xs` devices like this:

```
| A |
| B |
| C |
```

and I need them on `sm` devices rearranged like this:

```
| A | C |
| B |   |
```

The C column on `sm` devices should be col-sm-3.

Starting code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/u1fedjwq/

Please note that, this row of data will be repeated up to 100 times on the page with different data, this means any solution to duplicate a column by show or hide is dismissed.

As a side note, We can start from the sm order then arrange for mobile order, correct?

Comment: Use `col-sm-6` additionally to your `col-xs-12` classes. Bootstrap's default 12 column grid wraps onto the next line when your club count is greater then 12.

Comment: Can you post some code, where to add this col-sm-6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, adding some extra tags will solve this easily. Here it is

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 alert-success">
                    Column A <br/>
                    Column A <br/>
                    Column A <br/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 alert-danger">
                    Column B <br/>
                    Column B <br/>
                    Column B <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  alert-info">
            Column C <br/>
            Column C <br/>
            Column C <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If anyone have any problem with this snip, then please explain why..? I will be glad to learn it also, what is the problem with this..?

Comment: Your code seems to produce the result I need but my structure needs one row for the 3 columns because I still need other orders for the md and lg which I already have working, so restrict your solution to one row with three columns as I said in my question. Thanks for your effort, I up voted you anyway for your effort, do not know why some one else down voted you.

Comment: I changed my design to be based on your code instead of my original design, it just gave me the idea to start from your code. Then Re-arrange the columns for larger screens.

Answer (score 1):

Example code for a responsive one column layout on `xs` devices and two column layout on `sm` (and above, as long as there are no classes for `md` or `lg`) looks like this:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            Content A
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            Content B
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            Content C
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To reorder Content B and Content C on screens equal to or greater `sm` use the following skeleton:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            Content A
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
            Content B
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            Content C
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
            Content B
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Content B is duplicated (before and after Content C) and made visible depending on the screen sizes. I played around with `pull` and `push` classes, but with no luck. As long as Content B is not that large this should be a simple solution.

This code sample is also available at [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8gXTxD0NBR).

Comment: Your example is wrong. What I need is the last column C on the right of both columns A and B.

Comment: Sorry, last night I had in mind `C` was in the second row. I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u1fedjwq/3/)

you should use `**hidde-??** and **visible-??-??**` for your html structure. Because your purpose is particular so use the special code to resolve it.
There is code:

```
<div class="container">    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 alert-success">
        Column A <br/>
        Column A <br/>
        Column A <br/>
        Column A <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 alert-danger hidden-sm">
        Column B <br/>
        Column B <br/>
        Column B <br/>
    </div>   

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 alert-info">
        Column C <br/>
        Column C <br/>
        Column C <br/>
        Column C <br/>
        Column C <br/>
        Column C <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 alert-danger visible-sm-block">
        Column B <br/>
        Column B <br/>
        Column B <br/>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Even your code is wrong, your code means the data should be duplicated for columns B and C, this is a row of data on the page that will be repeated tens of times and this means data and page size will be over sized. Sure there are other solutions.